# Google GoogleClientSecrets.Load fails

Tags: c#, api, authentication, oauth, google-drive-api

I am trying to access my google drive account via console application and c#.
I have followed the instructions on:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet
and the application compiles just fine.
When running the application for the first time the debugger asked me where GoogleClientSecrets.cs was. I clicked cancel.
Now every time I call:

```
var d = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open));
```

I get the following object back:

```
d:
Installed   null    Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets
Secrets     'd.Secrets' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets {System.InvalidOperationException}
Web     null    Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets
```

and of course because of that the method GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync fails.
I have turned on the API in google dashboard and the json file (client_secret.json) does exist in the directory of the running binary.

suggestions on how to make the load function work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was a corrupted .json file. Can't believe I spend a couple of hours on this. Case closed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by corrupt?  I'm trying to use the one downloaded straight from the Credentials creator and I'm getting that same error.

Comment: I'm still not sure what my problem was, but in taking a look at some sample code I found that the sample used a plaintext API Key rather than the JSON file:

    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new 
    BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = "REPLACE_ME",
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
    });

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1309#issuecomment-437479636

> The code is mixing up service credentials and oauth credentials.
> ...if you've downloaded a service credential then don't use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker, that's for oauth.
> Create a credential like this: var cred = GoogleCredentials.FromFile().CreateScoped();

You would also need to .CreateWithUser() after CreateScoped() to let the service account act on-behalf of the user.

I have just now verified this.